# Can someone with a speech impediment recite the Qur'an?

Tags: quran-recitation, islamic-scholar

Muslims are meant to take the utmost care with the treatment of the Qur'an and in its recitation.

> The proper recitation of the Quran is the subject of a separate discipline named [tajwid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tajwid) which determines in detail how the Quran should be recited, how each individual syllable is to be pronounced, the need to pay attention to the places where there should be a pause, to elisions, where the pronunciation should be long or short, where letters should be sounded together and where they should be kept separate, etc. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quran#Rules_of_recitation)

However, this is a major obstacle to someone with a [speech impediment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_disorder) (stuttering, lisps, etc.), who may be incapable of correct recitation.

**Question**: Can someone with a speech impediment recite the Qur'an?

When I say "can" above, I'm asking about permissibility (i.e., halal/haram) and desirability in the case where someone is incapable of accurately reciting the Qur'an due to some biological impediment.  This is going to vary depending on the person's condition, and depending on how important it is for them to recite correctly (cf. an imam leading prayer vs. an everyday Muslim).

Obviously there's nobody physically stopping them picking up a Qur'an and reciting imperfectly, and moreover, reciting imperfectly will be part of the normal process of learning to recite the Qur'an.

Comment: Basically I've noticed that people stuttering can pretty well sing and I know good singers and Quran reciters who in daily life have issues to speak. So why shouldn't that be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can and are encouraged to do so basically because of the hadith saying:

> One who is proficient in the Qur'an is associated with the noble, upright, recording angels;
>
> - and he who falters in it, and finds it difficult for him, will have a double reward. (sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/290) and Sunan [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3779))
> - and he who falters when he recites the Qur'an and finds it difficult for him will have a double reward. (Sunan [abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/39))
> - Hisham said: "And it is hard for him" - Shu'bah said: "And it is difficult for him, - then he gets two rewards." (Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/731450))

Here you may see that at-Tirmdihi quoted that some narrators paraphrased what they heard. This doesn't mean that they heard something different, but could mean that they didn't recall the exact words they've heard.

So on the whole who ever does efforts to read/recite the Quran would get a reward for this especially if he has some issues like stuttering, lisps or can't speak Arabic.
Note that some speech impediments can be cured or treated and Arabs used to dislike hearing speeches of people who lisps so in some cases tribes used to break the teeth of the spokesmen of their enemies if they were too eloquent.