# Reading Quran with mistakes and rewards?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, reading-quran

If someone who started reading the Quran (from a mus'haf) for the first or second time in their life, read some words with a few mistakes but tried their best to read them by reading them a few times, do they still earn the rewards from Allah? The person who reads the Quran that way still understands the meaning of the surah or text. I know that when a person reads slowly earns rewards but what about someone who reads slowly and tries to read words but the words are somehow wrong? (but they don't know it's wrong)

Comment: Please read [Can someone with a speech impediment recite the qur'an](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37847/can-someone-with-a-speech-impediment-recite-the-quran/37849#37849) which should answer cover your inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

That’s fine! Allah know the purity in your heart!

the Prophet ﷺ said:

Verily the one who recites the Qur’an beautifully, smoothly, and precisely, he will be in the company of the noble and obedient angels. And as for the one who recites with difficulty, stammering or stumbling through its verses, then he will have twice that reward.” That’s including the one who makes mistake not knowing or not deliberately.